# Sending the server time as a response to HTTP GET via c# service

Tags: c#, json, datetime, service

Alright, I think I have it working 100% now!
Here's the code, any critique is welcome, this was my first attempt at c#, coming from a mostly JS background.
Ended up using thread.abort, not sure if that is the best way to end this. I put in a _shouldStop bool as well.

```
public partial class TimeReporterService : ServiceBase
{
    private Thread worker = null;
    private bool _shouldStop = false;

    public TimeReporterService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _shouldStop = false;
        worker = new Thread(SimpleListenerExample);
        worker.Name = "Time Reporter";
        worker.IsBackground = false;
        worker.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
        worker.Abort();
    }

    void SimpleListenerExample()
    {
        string[] prefixes = new[] { "http://*:12227/" };
        // URI prefixes are required, 
        // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        // Create a listener.
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        // Add the prefixes. 
        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
        }
        listener.Start();
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            // Obtain a response object.
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            // Construct a response. 
            string responseString = "{\"systemtime\":\"" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "\"}";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
        listener.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed where you said you were deploying this.  I doubt it's going to work.  What web server comes with that DVR?  I highly doubt you can deploy a .net application onto it.

Comment: It's NUUO's software. 
Yeah, doesn't seem like the webserver supports anything, I'd like to make a webserver service myself that just waits for a specific GET request and sends the time as a response. A string response would be fine, I could just parse it.
I found a simple webserver tutorial, that would be a good place to start I believe. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137979/Simple-HTTP-Server-in-C

Comment: What hardware is that running on?  Is it a windows machine?

Comment: Yeah windows 7 embedded. Don't want to run any third party server, just want a super lightweight server that responds with the time and nothing else. Plus I want to learn how to do it, this tutorial I found looks like a good place to start.
Going to try and make one as a console application before I change it into a service.

Comment: so, the question is, where is your doubt? Make the Web Server, if you have doubt about sending the date/time ask that then. When it's working do it in a Windows Service, and you have what you want.

Comment: Yup, I have it working in the console now. Going to try and change it into a service.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice guys, got it working as a service...well sort of. I created a new service project and just moved the code into it, removing any console writes. It runs as an exe but shows no console. It's not listed in services if you run service.msc though, so working on that next.

Comment: You need to register it. This tutorial has the register/unregister instructions http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Comment: Getting so close!!! I edited my original post to reflect the issues I'm having, but I'm so close I can taste it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you could use in the `HTTPListener` request method.

```
public void HttpListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
    HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
    HttpListenerResponse Response = context.Response;

    String dateAsString = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy h\:mm tt");

    byte[] bOutput = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dateAsString);
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    Response.ContentLength64 = bOutput.Length;

    Stream OutputStream = Response.OutputStream;
    OutputStream.Write(bOutput, 0, bOutput.Length);
    OutputStream.Close();
}
```

For this you should use HTTPListener in asynchronous (non-blocking) mode.
Ex:

```
public void NonblockingListener()
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8081/");
    listener.Start();
    IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(
        new AsyncCallback(HttpListenerCallback), listener);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for request to be processed asyncronously.");
    result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(); //just needed to don't close this thread, you can do other work or run in a loop
    Console.WriteLine("Request processed asyncronously.");
    listener.Close();
}
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.net.httplistener.aspx

Comment: Thanks man! I'm confused as to what (HttpListener)result.AsyncState does.

Comment: This method is for assyncronous mode. I updated my answer. Thanks.